# Not all of my child processes running the end of my for loop

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I have a project where I need to create N child processes and to do an election between them. So I've made so far a function to generate the random number (for the election, they have to compare the number they were attributed then the lower number is elected). Then, I'm stuck to make them communicate with pipes to compare the number. My problem is that only my first child process run the end of this for loop I really don't understand why. Here's all of my code so far :

```
void comparerIdElection(int (*pipes)[2], int numProc)
{


for (int i = 0; i < NBPROC; ++i)
    {
    if (numProc!=i)
    {
        close(pipes[i][0]);
        printf("je suis %d et je ferme la pipe [%d][0]\n",getpid(),i );
    }else printf("je suis %d et je laisse la pipe [%d][0] \n",getpid(),i );
    if (numProc +1 != i)
    {
        close(pipes[i][1]);
        printf("je suis %d et je ferme la pipe [%d][1]\n",getpid(),i );
    }else printf("je suis %d et je laisse la pipe [%d][1] \n",getpid(),i );
}


//Generate a random number for my child process
int GenererIdElection ()
{
    srand(time(NULL)^getpid()<<16);
    return rand()%NBPROC;
}






   int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int N = NBPROC, idElection, numProc= -1; 
    int pere = getpid();
/*Creation du nombre de pipe adequat */
    int pipes[N][2];
    int pids[N];
/* Indique l'etat du processus C = Candidat, B =B battu , E = Elu*/
    char etat ; 
    printf("le nombre de processus que je crée est : %d\n", N);


// Creation d'un nombre de N processus fils par le même pere
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
            if(getpid()==pere){
                fork() ; 
                numProc ++ ;
            }       
    }

    if (getpid() != pere)
    {
        pids[numProc] = getpid();
        etat = 'C';
        while(etat == 67)
        {
            idElection = GenererIdElection();
            printf("je suis %d et j'ai eu %d, mon num proc est %d \n",getpid(), idElection, numProc);
            comparerIdElection(pipes, numProc);
            printf("hop\n");
            etat ='B';
            
        }

    }


    if (getpid()==pere)
    {
    /*On attend la fin de chaque processus
     pour mettre un terme au processu pere*/
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            wait(&pids[i]);
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

And here is what happens once executed (I translated all of printf) :

[terminal][1]

Edit : As I can't post image due to a lack of reputation I copy/pasta :

I'm 1854 i got 1, my numproc is : 0 
I'm 1854 i don't close pipe [0][0] 
I'm 1854 i close [0][1] 
I'm 1854 i close pipe [1][0] 
I'm 1854 i don't close pipe [1][1] 
I'm 1854 i close pipe [2][0] 
I'm 1854 i close [2][1] 
hop
I'm 1855 i got 1, my numproc is : 1 
I'm 1855 i close pipe [0][0]
I'm 1855 i close [0][1]
I'm 1855 i don't close pipe [1][0] 
I'm 1856 i got 1, my numproc is : 2 
I'm 1856 i close pipe [0][0]
I'm 1856 i close [0][1]
I'm 1856 i close pipe [1][0]

NB : NBPROC = 3 in this case, but no matter the Number of value it does not work except for the very first child processes.

Comment: Where are the pipe fd's being set up, else most of the `close()` are just returning `-EBADF`?

Comment: Oh damn, you right such a ridiculous mistake, but I'm wondering then why is it working for the first process child and when i=0, if you have a clue about this : I'm taking it. 
Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Did my explanation work for your case? Was it the actual cause that one of the `fd`s was always set to 1?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a plausible explanation for the behavior of your program. As I've already pointed out in the comments, there is an obvious flaw in the program that the `int pipes[N][2];` weren't set up which would end up in the `close()` APIs actually just leading to `EBADF` being returned and probably not achieving what had been intended.

As for your program's behavior, that can be explained by inspecting the actual values being populated in the array `int pipes[N][2];`. Since the values aren't being set explicitly in the original question, the values are essentially undefined but...

Let's try setting them to something more *sane* values using:

```
int pipeVal = INT32_MIN;
if(argc == 2) {
    pipeVal = atoi(argv[1]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    if(pipeVal != INT32_MIN) {
        pipes[i][0] =  pipes[i][1] = pipeVal;
    }
    printf("%d: Pipe pair %d-%d\n",getpid(), pipes[i][0], pipes[i][1]);
}
```

Passing in 0 yields the output:

```
61962: Number of process is : 3
61962: Pipe pair 0-0
61962: Pipe pair 0-0
61962: Pipe pair 0-0
61963: Election Id 0, numProc 0 
61963: Exiting while-loop
61964: Election Id 0, numProc 1 
61964: Exiting while-loop
61965: Election Id 0, numProc 2 
61965: Exiting while-loop
```

This seems to align with what's expected: fork 3 processes which just exit eventually. Let's try with the value of 1

```
62033: Number of process is : 3
62033: Pipe pair 1-1
62033: Pipe pair 1-1
62033: Pipe pair 1-1
62034: Election Id 0, numProc 0 
62035: Election Id 2, numProc 1 
62036: Election Id 0, numProc 2
```

Now this *appears* to be weird since none of the processes actually exit out of the while loop, yet the main program terminates successfully. To actually check the exit status of the child programs, I added the following code:

```
if (getpid()==pere)
{
/*On attend la fin de chaque processus
 pour mettre un terme au processu pere*/
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        errno = 0;
        int stat_val;
        wait(&stat_val);
        #if DBG == 1
        printf("%d: WIFEXITED(%d),WEXITSTATUS(%d),WIFSIGNALED(%d),WTERMSIG(%d),WIFSTOPPED(%d),WSTOPSIG(%d),WIFCONTINUED(%d)\n", getpid(), WIFEXITED(stat_val),WEXITSTATUS(stat_val),WIFSIGNALED(stat_val),WTERMSIG(stat_val),WIFSTOPPED(stat_val),WSTOPSIG(stat_val),WIFCONTINUED(stat_val));
        #endif
    }
}
```

Here's the output on passing in 1 as the argument:

```
62215: WIFEXITED(1),WEXITSTATUS(0),WIFSIGNALED(0),WTERMSIG(0),WIFSTOPPED(0),WSTOPSIG(0),WIFCONTINUED(0)
62215: WIFEXITED(1),WEXITSTATUS(0),WIFSIGNALED(0),WTERMSIG(0),WIFSTOPPED(0),WSTOPSIG(0),WIFCONTINUED(0)
62215: WIFEXITED(1),WEXITSTATUS(0),WIFSIGNALED(0),WTERMSIG(0),WIFSTOPPED(0),WSTOPSIG(0),WIFCONTINUED(0)
```

This output indicates that  ***all*** the processes exited normally without being stopped abnormally by any signal whatsoever.

The clue is in the actual `fd`s these processes are trying to close. In Linux (at least) a process once created has 3 file descriptors `0` for `stdin`, `1` for `stdout`, and `2` for `stderr`. When 0 is passed as an argument to the program, the processes just end up closing `stdin` (`close(0)`) which isn't being used anyway, hence no issues, and they exit `comparerIdElection()` and the while-loop subsequently. When 1 is passed in as a parameter to the program, the processes end up closing `stdout` (`close(1)`), hence whatever is supposed to be written to the output is not seen on the console anymore, yet they *still* do exit  `comparerIdElection()` and the while-loop subsequently and thus the `WIFEXITED(1)` from each process.

Now coming to the actual program shared, what are the actual values that end up getting populated is unspecified, but if even one of the `N*2` `fd`s in the array is set to 1, the behavior as above (passing in 1) shall be exhibited i.e. even though the `printf`s won't be written to the console, the processes do actually exit the while-loop and the main parent process is successfully able to wait for the processes. On my PC (and I suspect on yours too), the actual value of at least one of those array elements is always set to 1.

Values of pipe fd pairs on my Mac:

```
61120: Pipe pair -296602944-32766
61120: Pipe pair 23978080-1
61120: Pipe pair 64-0
```

Their values on [TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##tVd/b9s2EP3fn@LSwgsVy7OdAh1QRwPyww0MpIpRO@0AzwtUiXaIypImyemKwV997pEUZVKynSDbhACWjkfeu7vHR8ZvL3x/s3nNIj9cBRTOsjxg8c8Pvza2plXE0Gra0BCyL6YtZ0ta8fqedb55LDetNE2juLpcyqJFLQSLxNTGY8wC8ONl4qU0HQaDkPo5iyOC40BOEpbQzJqezmzghmi1HKWxbzX@bgA@8zgF4cjAgW4ff87AvRh9vL3sQ6vFLOEkXfnD5kCKFY6cYtT04M9rdLu6uAbHgZ4xkGAe@Zy8agbv4IJibAp@GGcURxAlTJvBbNqdkWZg/R69shc0T1hALJuBLRyyKePjVt@MRqOAzQ2TqKFIyDCLWOTAShL3XshiflAHC83MxGvAtQH7h4jilAhc1mH8a6Ahr8gLSoo5e6L1gH81kAcgwhOQdvUfWj04cuD/IUFvBwk0xL2nED@fBL09JDiMWwKu4j3Eg16dB/AsIvwrHtQQvrykkgTrxrrR6HSuaURTL6fgQepFQbzkuvKFpkJPlt/Bf2BhgJhin2ZZg@uLmKHLExClQRlfgnB9JO7dzY31hwJ4dtZ7W4BKab5KIxGMWM1CoTgWvvbSY1LtvHTh2xjcS1EPoyyHE7Q8TmcqEvdxkRJyPgpiicZWwuhAu9eH0jtB0DhBIepvB0Th3BkKq24MuE0aBAyaeznIb71DrqxWPFc1ApbBO2gGvD9lNBvcSsRPXohohu7kzen9h6FbDM4JT5xz4tTS@LKd4OUxI6IUJd3XSv5r6i@F3xB9opY60oJbFWrqeuKAwSxHYenv0BS9LiPO18RjKZaiLauxLYahqfUNjGTYe6LtOcyIWtxxeKOtakLBvegpLoSrfiUWmDukoEyrZZpFvQLejm61RvzpdCALKU1Ir1vZcQc3eLVU5/Nc7revyA7IH2ix6RZxLqxtjqFGKPzZFbSunjvVp6hKNi0yl50N/tMs@C0Gu1dJQ9WavwoEqGkYXOZXi8AfI@dye2svRiLPLEpNDRvqVFTh@BYRXKqQDbtuSHSZTqVB6n62xSMkxIHjy@Ot7Ru2mhI54sDbX/YdwluBwxVqEkwqWesAy3lDXn5br7@5K3doaGXZHVdTsXv3@cu0ji@On1KLwV8sx4uxrEY7jOPEKKapC3qTiu2utahzchuhTObYcwg9mCMZA76jvD9XVGn0KpMokniFhxzN8TSHFZKWpks8CFelm@j/SaeE/JQi1du25@rC18iwOPePupIKPuC/EeQnNfaSG83n4fvBb8PJ4IpfE@zP/H08OZ/cjeX38P14eO2e36jxyeDjB7SUg5Pb0UiN8Q9t7PLWnQzdOzlaYfs2aondiK1ZNQSaVeEwHQs0mlFhMvy2yErz8@5A@4hYMGAXCym6EJ7Z/fju8nIwHqN9vdn8489Db5Ft2lfyTuK8wVdsltP9AQ):

```
25090: Pipe pair 0-0
25090: Pipe pair 68079952-32708
25090: Pipe pair 1-0
```

Their values on [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/ryvWPcOBd) (need to add the compiler flag `-DNBPROC=3`):

```
5612: Pipe pair 1505064448-32611                                                                                                                                         
5612: Pipe pair 1507242440-32611                                                                                                                                         
5612: Pipe pair 1-0
```

This analysis should hold irrespective of the value of `NBPROC` since till there's 1 amongst the pipe `fd`s, that process will end up closing its own `stdout` and exhibit similar behavior.

Here's the complete program with some instrumentation that can be enabled by passing in `DBG=1` and some PID-tagging to figure out which process is the log from :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void comparerIdElection(int (*pipes)[2], int numProc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NBPROC; ++i)
    {
        if (numProc!=i)
        {
            #if DBG == 1
            printf("%d: Before close  pipe [%d][0](%d)\n",getpid(),i , pipes[i][0]);
            #endif
            errno = 0;
            close(pipes[i][0]);
            #if DBG
            printf("%d: closed  pipe [%d][0](%d) %s\n",getpid(),i, pipes[i][0], strerror(errno));
            #endif
        } else  {
            #if DBG == 1
            printf("%d: no action on pipe [%d][0](%d) \n",getpid(),i, pipes[i][0] );
            #endif
        }
        if (numProc +1 != i)
        {
            #if DBG == 1
            printf("%d: Before close  pipe [%d][1](%d)\n",getpid(),i, pipes[i][1] );
            #endif
            errno = 0;
            close(pipes[i][1]);
            #if DBG == 1
            printf("%d: close pipe [%d][1](%d) %s\n",getpid(),i, pipes[i][1], strerror(errno) );
            #endif
        } else {
            #if DBG == 1
            printf("%d: no action pipe [%d][1](%d) \n",getpid(),i, pipes[i][1] );
            #endif
        }
    }
}

//Generate a random number for my child process
int GenererIdElection ()
{
    srand(time(NULL)^getpid()<<16);
    return rand()%NBPROC;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int N = NBPROC, idElection, numProc= -1; 
    int pere = getpid();
    int pipes[N][2];
    int pids[N];
    char etat ;
    printf("%d: Number of process is : %d\n", getpid(), N);
    int pipeVal = INT32_MIN;
    if(argc == 2) {
        pipeVal = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if(pipeVal != INT32_MIN) {
            pipes[i][0] =  pipes[i][1] = pipeVal;
        }
        printf("%d: Pipe pair %d-%d\n",getpid(), pipes[i][0], pipes[i][1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if(getpid()==pere){
            pid_t pid = fork() ;
            numProc++;
            if(pid == 0) {
                // sleep(10);
                #if DBG == 1
                printf("%d: After fork in the child got fork-pid %d\n", getpid(), pid);
                #endif
            } else {
                pids[numProc] = pid;
                #if DBG == 1
                printf("%d: After fork in the parent got fork-pid %d numProc %d pids[%d] = %d\n",
                    getpid(), pid, numProc, numProc, pids[numProc]);
                #endif
            }
        }
    }

    if (getpid() != pere)
    {
        etat = 'C';
        while(etat == 67)
        {
            idElection = GenererIdElection();
            printf("%d: Election Id %d, numProc %d \n",getpid(), idElection, numProc);
            comparerIdElection(pipes, numProc);
            etat ='B';
        }
        printf("%d: Exiting while-loop\n", getpid());
    }

    if (getpid()==pere)
    {
    /*On attend la fin de chaque processus
     pour mettre un terme au processu pere*/
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            errno = 0;
            int stat_val;
            wait(&stat_val);
            #if DBG == 1
            printf("%d: WIFEXITED(%d),WEXITSTATUS(%d),WIFSIGNALED(%d),WTERMSIG(%d),WIFSTOPPED(%d),WSTOPSIG(%d),WIFCONTINUED(%d)\n", getpid(), WIFEXITED(stat_val),WEXITSTATUS(stat_val),WIFSIGNALED(stat_val),WTERMSIG(stat_val),WIFSTOPPED(stat_val),WSTOPSIG(stat_val),WIFCONTINUED(stat_val));
            #endif
        }
    }
    printf("%d: Exiting process\n", getpid());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```